# Botfront Development is not working. RASA instance not reachable. Train button is disabled

Tags: node.js, meteor, chatbot, mern, rasa-nlu

I'm trying to install botfront 1.0.5 in my local machine (Ubuntu 18.04) using botfront source code(Development), following the exact instructions in this page https://github.com/botfront/botfront.

[Botfront Development Installation Guide](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hyS1_UoVTOLOfXX2by1MVNk3MwjOjXJh/view?usp=sharing)

So I ran all the above said commands, but I am getting the error :
Rasa instance not reachable and my Train Button is also not enabled.

I am sharing my screen shots below :

Note : I have set the project-id also using botfront set-project <project_id> and have cross checked also inside botfront.yml

These are my Project Settings.

I have also tried replacing my **localhost** with my **machine IP address**, but still getting the same error. Then I have changed the db config from **bf-os** to **bf** under package.json file.

**"start:docker-compose.dev": "MODE=development BF_PROJECT_ID=bf MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/bf meteor run"**

When I am running **botfront up** (complete botfront service) inside my project folder, and running **meteor npm run start:docker-compose.dev** inside my source code folder, I can see the **Train Button** is enabled but it is fluctuating again and again (enabling / disabling) and I can train the project successfully.

But I am facing another problem here, i.e. after completion of training, when I am testing the chatbot, it is showing me its **utterance_id** rather than its **original message content**.

And below is my Server Side log screen shot.

Please help me to find the solution so that I can successfully run the project from the source code and can deploy it.

**All the screenshots and complete problem can be found here.[Complete Problem Statement](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hyS1_UoVTOLOfXX2by1MVNk3MwjOjXJh/view?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**

- use `botfront up -e botfront` instead of `botfront up` to start the rasa and action container, to avoid starting the botfront container
- configure `BF_URL` to the correct host and port

**Long Explanation**

Your problem is likely, that you have 2 instances of botfront running simultaneously. Inside the empty botfront project, which you use to run the rasabot and action containers, you used the command `botfront up`. This will run docker-compose and start all containers, including the botfront container. Instead `botfront up -e botfront` is the correct command. See https://botfront.io/docs/contributing

Make sure to configure the `BF_URL` endpoint for botfront correctly inside the empty project `.env` file. Otherwise the rasa container will not be able to establish the connection. The rasa container needs to be able to connect to the botfront instance to fetch the bot text responses.